# Remove duplicate mails from mailing list

Tags: email, thunderbird

If I write to a mailing list, some people reply to the list and additional put me into CC.

This way I receive the reply twice:

- once via mailing list
- once via CC

In thunderbird I would like to see the mail only once, not twice.

Is there a way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately Thunderbird has a [plugin available](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/remove-duplicate-messages-alte/) to help cleanup this mess. You can download it from the link above and [install it normally.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/installing-addon-thunderbird#w_download)

Another option would be to notify the members of the mailing list that CC'ing results in duplicates and why. Perhaps this would result in a decrease of this illogical behavior.

Comment: Looks good. Does not solve the issue if I use K9 (android mail user agent), but helps for thunderbird. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: It's only expected to work for Thundrbird as that's what yoru question was about. If you need assistance with android, https://android.stackexchange.com/ would be a great place to start

Comment: I see. I need two tools to solve one problem...

Comment: @guettli   You may find this useful https://k9mail.github.io/documentation/faq.html

Comment: I could not find a matching question in the FAQ. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/940234/remove-duplicate-mails-from-mailing-list/941014?noredirect=1#comment1494695_941014

Comment: you link points to this question at StackO, not to the k9 FAQ. I don't understand what you want to say to me.

Comment: I looked at your StackO profile. Your words of wisdom look interesting. Unfortunately I am not a native speaker. I guess I could need about five sentences of explanation for each line you wrote. I am curious.

Comment: You must have clicked on my name rather than the link which at the risk of repeating myself suggested that  If you need assistance with android, https://android.stackexchange.com would be a great place to start. Unforunately, Mein Deutsch ist nicht gut.

Comment: yes I clicked on your name, but with intention. I like words of wisdom in general and would like to understand your words of wisdom. Back to the topic: I think I need help with IMAP. K9 und Thunderbird are just the graphical user interfaces.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: I opened a new question. What should I do with this (old) question? Here is the new: https://askubuntu.com/questions/943763/remove-duplicate-mails-from-mailing-list-imap

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this question as originally written. Others with the issue of duplicate emails in `thunderbird` will likely benefit from your original question and my answer.