# Remove duplicate mails from mailing list (IMAP)

Tags: android, email, thunderbird, imap

If I write to a mailing list, some people reply to the list and additional put me into CC.

This way I receive the reply twice:

- once via mailing list
- once via CC

In thunderbird (Ubuntu) and K9 (Android) I would like to see the mail only once, not twice.

Is there a way to achieve this goal?

I think a solution plugin for thunderbird won't help, since if I don't start my ubuntu PC, the thunderbird plugin can't clean up, and I will see the duplicates in K9.

I access the mails via IMAP.

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu. Better to ask on maybe https://serverfault.com/ how to configure your mailing list to prevent duplicate messages. I know that mailman can do that. http://www.list.org/mailman-member/node21.html

Answer (score 1):

Of course if you don't start your Ubuntu PC, no solution for Ubuntu will work for you, just as if you don't start your car it won't get you to work.

Now that we've cleared up that confusion, If you are using IMAP on both devices, the answer provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/941014/225694) should work without issue as 
whenever Thunderbird starts, it checks the state of synchronization between the Thunderbird message repository and the email server, and then performs any transfers that are necessary (such as downloading new messages from the server, **deleting from the server any messages that have been deleted locally**, etc). Thunderbird continually synchronizes with the email server as long as it is running and has access to the internet. If internet access is lost, Thunderbird will synchronize when access is reestablished.

If you are looking for a solution that doesn't require starting Ubuntu you are looking for a solution for Android and you should ask [here.](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a solution which works even if thunderbird is not running.

Comment: Please forgive my confusion, but what part of "If you are looking for a solution that doesn't require starting Ubuntu you are looking for a solution for Android and you should ask [here.](https://android.stackexchange.com/)" was difficult for you to parse? Why would you look for an answer that runs on Ubuntu here if you wan't an answer that doesn't require you to "start my ubuntu PC"? I wish you the best of luck and reccommend that you review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask